# Hyperbola Ratio of Segments with Transformation

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Let H be a hyperbola with center Z. Points A and B are selected on H. Suppose that the tangents to H at points A and B intersect at a point C distinct from A, B, Z. Prove that line ZC passes through a point X in the interior of segment AB and determine the ratio AX/AB.

Comment: points $A$ and $B$ on the same branch, I suppose

Comment: @G Cab yes. they are on the same branch.

Comment: Are you sure this is not from an ongoing [MIT math contest](https://math.mit.edu/research/highschool/primes/materials/2017/entpro2017gen.pdf)? IIRC their rules about external help prohibit asking questions like this around.